# How was excession expressed in Proto-Germanic?

Tags: semantics, proto-germanic

The state of excession (of an adjective) is indicated differently accross Germanic languages.

West Germanic Languages (E: too long, Du: te lang, G: zu lang) build it by the use of descendants from Proto-Germanic *to/*ta meaning „to“/“at“,
North Germanic Languages (N: for lenge, D: for langt, SE: för länge) use descendants from *furi/*furai („for“/“before“)
and IS „of lengi“ seems to come from *uber („over“).

Comprehensive but different imaginations are behind theese concepts.

**Are there any approaches on reconstructing a Proto-Germanic form of expressing a state of excession?**
Or - if not - is there any guess, which of the forms above is probably the oldest?